# Exporting diectory structure to csv/xl file

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, directory

my requirement is to  enumerate all directories and specific .tif files (that are at the end of the structure). Sample is

```
                         A (path selected from UI) <has>
                   B<has>             and              C<has>
       D <has>         E           F              G             H      I        J
K         L<has>
       1.tif   2.tif
```

In the above directory, A has B and C. Named as clients. B has D,E,F (as dated), D has K and L (family).
So Ineed your help in retrieving the directory structure in txt or excel file as

```
B                  D  
                       K    0
                       L    2 (since there are two tif files)


                   E
                   F
```

Similary for c and other directories.

Comment: Sorry, but your sample makes no sense as written. Could you edit it or describe in more detail what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Are you trying to export some directory structure as a tree (as columns) with count of .tif files on leaves? A recursive or parsing function would be great for that. Inspiration: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx

Comment: In the above xl, you we have. AH as root directory. It has a directory 20100714. The 20100714 has multiple directories having name abc.fof, def.fof, ghi.fof and so on. Then each .fof directory has xyz.bat and other multiple .bat directories.. Each .bat directory has directory named images that contains images. So what i want is to export the stated directory struture as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this would do the trick (or give at least a good start point):

```
public void OutputStructureToFile(string outputFileName, string folder, string searchPattern)
{
    using (var file = new StreamWriter(outputFileName))
    {
        file.Write(GetStructure(new DirectoryInfo(folder), searchPattern));
    }
}

public string GetStructure(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo, string searchPattern)
{
    return GetStructureRecursive(directoryInfo, searchPattern, 0);
}

private string GetStructureRecursive(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo, string searchPattern, int level)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    var indentation = level * 5;

    sb.Append(new String(' ', indentation));
    sb.AppendLine(directoryInfo.Name);

    foreach (var directory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
    {
        sb.Append(GetStructureRecursive(directory, searchPattern, level+1));
    }

    var groupedByExtension = directoryInfo.GetFiles(searchPattern)
                                          .GroupBy(file => file.Extension)
                                          .Select(group => new { Group = group.Key, Count = group.Count() });

    foreach (var entry in groupedByExtension)
    {
        sb.Append(new String(' ', indentation));
        sb.AppendLine(String.Format("   {0,10} {1,3}", entry.Group, entry.Count));
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

And if you need it for Excel as a .csv file you should instead use this recursive function

```
private string GetStructureRecursiveForCsv(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo, string searchPattern, int level)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    var indentation = level;

    sb.Append(new String(';', indentation));
    sb.AppendLine(directoryInfo.Name);

    foreach (var directory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
    {
        sb.Append(GetStructureRecursiveForCsv(directory, searchPattern, level+1));
    }

    var groupedByExtension = directoryInfo.GetFiles(searchPattern)
                                          .GroupBy(file => file.Extension)
                                          .Select(group => new { Group = group.Key, Count = group.Count() });

    foreach (var entry in groupedByExtension)
    {
        sb.Append(new String(';', indentation));
        sb.AppendLine(String.Format(";{0};{1}", entry.Group, entry.Count));
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understand what you want but here is something that to get you started

```
    private static void ProcessFolder(string folder, string level, string separator, StreamWriter output)
    {
        var dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(folder);
        foreach ( var d in dirs )
        {
            output.Write(level);
            output.WriteLine(d);
            ProcessFolder(d, level + separator, separator, output);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(folder);
        foreach ( var f in files )
        {
            output.Write(level);
            output.WriteLine(f);
        }
    }
```

You will have to customize it to filter TIFF or whatever you want. You can call this function like this and it will generate the file

```
        using ( var output = new StreamWriter(@"C:\test.csv") )
        {
            ProcessFolder(@"c:\Program files", "", ";", output);
        }
```

Double-click on the generated file and Excel will probably open :)